# How to safely rely on Ajax data being present

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I'm currently working on a SharePoint 2013 solution and we are using Javascript and jQuery extensively. I've come across a rather irritating problem that I can't seem to figure out. Please keep in mind that I have not used Javascript much in the past.

I have a picture library list in my SharePoint solution, which holds pictures for a webpart that uses the Slides.js framework to display pictures. To retrieve the pictures, I have to use Ajax to get the pictures from the library list, and then apply slidesjs to my div-container in the .ascx-file.

Since Ajax returns the data when it's ready, I can not be sure if the data is present at the time I apply the slides.js framework to the unordered list in my markup. The data might be there, or it might not. And as you might've guessed; if it's not there, it simply does not work.

To bypass the problem for demo purposes, I've added a setTimeout, so that slides.js isn't applied untill 300ms has passed, but this is an ugly fix that I want to get rid of. And, it's not stable.

So to wrap up, my question is basically; is it possible to safely rely on Ajax data to be present at a time, and if so, how?

Feel free to ask for additional information.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** *Added code*

Here is my ajax options

```
var ajaxOpts = {
    url: web + endpoint,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
}
```

And successHandler

```
function successHandler (response) {
    // Do response parsing

    setTimeout(function () {
        runSlider(); // basically jQuery("#slider").slidesjs(slidesOpts)
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the code for your AJAX call and for when you apply slider.

Comment: Normally you would put all your code into the callback then, which is executed once the AJAX is there. Or never if it is never there, e.g. due to network outage. That is safe. Keyword: event-oriented programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your code is in the success or complete callback, you can be sure that the data is available for it.

There are two ways to get to the success and complete callbacks. Inside the options of $.ajax:

```
$.ajax("foo.php",{
    type: "get",
    success: function(data){
        // do something with data, it is available within this scope
    },
    complete: function(data){
        // do something with data, it is available within this scope
    }
})
```

or use the methods of the jqXHR

```
$.ajax("foo.php",{
    type: "get"
}).done(function(data){
    // do something with data, it is available within this scope
}).always(function(data){
    // do something with data, it is available within this scope
});
```

Note, you can also pass the xhr around your code as needed so that you can use data elsewhere safely.

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax("foo.php",{
    type: "get"
});
$("#someEl").click(function(){
    jqXHR.done(function(data){
        // do something with data
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice answers, Kevin. May I just point out something very minor. The OP has asked "Is it possible to safely rely on Ajax data to be present at a time, and if so, how?". Unfortunately, none of your examples guarantee response data. The SUCCESS callback will let the client-side know that it connected OK (status 200 OK), and COMPLETE when it finishes, but doesn't necessarily return any data. Maybe you could chuck some IF statements in there to be sure of data being returned. Minor, I know, but few newbies...

Comment: If data is empty string or undefined, that's still data.

Comment: It is still data, yes, but it's not slides like the OP wants. Never mind, I admit is a very petty suggestion. It's just if he does get an `undefined` or `null`, he will get problems. Forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

In cases you need to do some sort of 'synchronizity' involving ajax requests,I see 2 options:

1. [jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)
2. [Ajax async](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/&ei=BYGoUrz1DISwyQG7zICoBA&usg=AFQjCNF1ITsE5bJBc65MY4nqhZq7OkHZpg&bvm=bv.57799294,d.aWc) : false in your request

I DO recommend the first one given that is a more elegant and performant solution. async: false can freeze the browser

Usage example:

jQuery deferreds:

```
$.when(ajaxRequest).done(function(){
...//do stuff with sliders
});

or using async false:

$.ajax({
    url : "/controller/action",
    async : false,
    ...
    success: function(){
    ...// do stuff 
    }
})
```

If you do not have complex requirements, just do as other answers suggests and do stuff in your ajax `success` call

Comment: But won't the success callback just say "Yes, it is a success, and you will receive the data - when available." Not "It was a success and you now have the data"? I might be completely off!

Comment: Once reached the success callback means that the request ended up without any errors, normally this will lead for having the data you want back.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `success` or `complete` callbacks in the AJAX request. When the AJAX completes, run your function putting slides in slider.

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: myURL.php,
   dataType: "html",
   complete: function (data) {
       if (data !== null && data !== undefined) { // make sure data has been returned
           // add slides here
       } else {
           alert("Slides not available");
       }
   }, error: function() {
       alert("Slides not available");
   }
});
```

Then you can be sure that when the AJAX has been run, and was successful, your adding slides feature will work as expected.

You could also do something a bit more involved like this, as an alternative. This is useful if you're calling multiple AJAX request and want to know when both have completed before doing the work.

```
$.when(ajax1(), ajax2()).done(function(a1, a2) {
    // the code here will be executed when both AJAX requests complete
    // a1 & a2 contain lists of 3 items; the response text [0],
    // the status [1], and an jqXHR object [2] for each of the listed AJAX calls
    if (a1[0]) {
        // add slides here
    }
    if (a2[0]) {
        // do something else here
    }
});

function ajax1() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: myURL.php,
        dataType: "html"
    });
}

function ajax2() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: myURL.php,
        dataType: "html"
    });
}
```